# Conditional regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am currently trying to match the following using a regular expression:

```
label      string
  a        disvt
  b        disv2
  c        disv1
  d        disv1f
  e        disv10
  f        disr1
```

I am trying to capture vt, v2, v1 and v10, using a conditional regular expression to capture the last 3 in that list.

The regular expression I have so far captures vt and v10 but omits v1 and v2. I'm not entirely sure how to create a regex that captures the first digit if there is only one digit after the 'v' and the first two digits if there are two digits after the 'v'

What I have below captures v10 and vt, which I want, however it omits v2 and v1.

```
desired_df['new_column'] = df["string"].str.extract(pat="(r\d{1}|vt|v\d{1}?\d(?(1)\w))", expand=False)
```

Desired output would have

```
desired_df['new_column'].value_counts()

r1  1
vt  1 
v10 1
v1  1
v2  1
```

Final new dataframe:

```
    label     string    new_column
     a        disvt            vt
     b        disv2           NaN
     c        disv1           NaN
     d        disv1f          NaN
     e        disv10          v10
     f       disr1            r1
```

Comment: You could get all digits in group 2 using a conditional `v(?:t|((\d)(?(2)\d*)))` https://regex101.com/r/wOkY7I/1 but using a single group might be better `v(?:t|(\d+))\b` https://regex101.com/r/FfeAdc/1

Comment: hmm, perhaps I am not understanding something. When I use:  "(r\d{1}|v(?:t|(\d+))\b)"  the only group captured is r1. Thank you for your help on this!

Comment: You can see in the regex demo that there are more matches https://regex101.com/r/DNc8C5/1 Can you add your code to the question so we can have a better understanding of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Do you want this as your output `2, 1, NaN, 10, NaN`

Comment: As an aside, `{1}` is never useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
v(?:t|\d{1,2})\b
```

> (?:t|\d{1,2}) : mean t character or digit with size between 1 and 2 
> (?!\w) : not followed by alphanumeric character

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/UgiWGE/2)

Comment: You can safely replace `(?!\w)` with `\b` (granted the regex is implemented as a raw string literal).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i know but its the same because \b equal to (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W) and that's mean not \w witch same as (?!\w)

Comment: Right, but `\b` is shorter. People like it short.